# Editing a program with Ollydbg

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, inline-assembly, ollydbg

This is my C++ code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func1()
{
    static int _count = 0;
    if (_count < 5)
    {
        __asm
        {
            pop eax
            push func1
        }
    }

    _count++;
    cout << _count << endl;
}

int main()
{
    func1();

    cout << "ok" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I need to remove asm inline.

It is loaded into Ollydbg, and this is position of asm inline:
[image]

I will fill two instructions which is marked in the image with NOP's. Ok. I know how to do it. Then, I saved it with a new name.

But when I loaded the program that I edited into Ollydbg.
The places that I edited was added a new instruction.

[image]

And the new instruction makes the program crashs.

Ok, If my question is clearly enough, I need to know:
How did that instruction was added automatically?
And How do I fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**
The following is how I modified the program
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But.. I don't know why?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `NOP` allocates 1 byte, so to replace those two instructions by `NOP`s

```
POP  EAX              ; 1 byte
PUSH Console.func1    ; 5 byte
```

You need to put 6 of `NOP` not 2. Otherwise, you have 2 `NOP`s and 4 bytes of garbage.

Comment: It seems that he used the option 'Fill with NOP's' and got 90909090**80**90 instead of 909090909090.